# Getting error while posting tar.gz file using http client but works fine with curl command

Tags: java

Please find the sender class below

```
private static CloseableHttpClient httpClient() {
        try {
            TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (certificate, authType) -> true;
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(acceptingTrustStrategy, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                    .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
                    .register("https", sf)
                    .build();
            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
            connectionManager.setMaxTotal(maxTotalConnections);
            connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnectionsPerRoute);
            CloseableHttpClient defaultHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.DEFAULT)
                    .build();

            return defaultHttpClient;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    static String authHeaders(String username, String password ){

        String auth = username + ":" + password;
        String authHeader = "Basic " + auth;
        return authHeader;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://localhost:8018/receiver?filename=data.tar.gz");
            //postRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING, "chunked");
            postRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeaders("test","test") );
            postRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip");
            File file = new File(Receiver.class.getClassLoader().getResource("data.tar.gz").getFile());
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

            builder.addPart("data.tar.gz", new FileBody(file, "application/x-gzip"));

            postRequest.setEntity(builder.build());

//            MultipartEntity multipart = new MultipartEntity();
//            ContentBody fileContent = new FileBody(file); //For tar.gz: "application/x-gzip"
//            multipart.addPart("data.tar.gz", fileContent);
//            postRequest.setEntity(multipart);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I am trying to post gzip file through http client and getting below error

```
com.filter.GzipFilter|Error on reading gz file: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)
    at com.filter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Getting error while posting tar.gz file using http client  but If I post the same file using curl command it works fine and executes properly but while passing through http client throws error.

Curl command

```
curl -u test:test --insecure -T ./data.tar.gz -v -X POST  --header "Content-Encoding: gzip" 'https://localhost:8018/receiver?filename=data.tar.gz'
```

Please check and let me know what I am missing and I tried to search and got some details and implemented using the same but not yet got a solution.

Comment: please share your full curl command that works fine.

Comment: added curl command for reference @miradham

Comment: I can only guess that you are malforming archive somehow.

Comment: Your file part is gzipped, but your request (i.e. the multipart as a whole) is not. Do NOT set encoding=gzip on the post. Alternatively do like curl does and do NOT use multipart, use the file directly as the request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to enable chunked to resolve the issue.

```
File file = new File(CallHttpReceiver.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile());
FileEntity fileEntity = new FileEntity(file);
fileEntity.setChunked(true);   
postRequest.setEntity( fileEntity );
```

We need to make our fileEntity as chunked to pass the gzip as a request and it worked for me . Thanks to all who supported and tried to provide result for me.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work

```
File file = new File(Receiver.class.getClassLoader().getResource("data.tar.gz").getFile());
```

**Resources are not files**

You wont be able to access that resource once you will pack your app into file.

Use `InputStreamBody` instead like

```
InputStream in=Receiver.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data.tar.gz");
     builder.addPart("data.tar.gz", new InputStreamBody( in,"application/x-gzip"));
```

This is just example. Remeber to close input stream after request.

Comment: still facing the same issue @Antoniossss

Comment: Thanks for your support @Antoniossss